# Get console output from virtual machine started on command line

Tags: bash, virtual-machine, virtualbox

When starting a virtual machine from the command line on a remote computer via
`VBoxManage startvm "vm_name" --type headless`, is there a way to collect the output of the guest operating system on start up? The ultimate goal is to handle and manipulate the vm from a bash shell or python script, but some information that is printed out during start up is needed for that.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to "Settings" of your Virtual Machine in VirtualBox.
- Select "Ports"
- Enable Serial Port and provide a port/file path that will store the data on your host.

On the virtual machine, edit your boot options and add `console=ttyS0 console=tty0 ignore_loglevel`

From there, you should be able to tail the file you specified in the Serial Port section.

Source:
http://techvolve.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-redirect-linux-guest-output-of.html

Comment: Many thanks for the link. Is there a way to add the boot options "console=ttyS0 console=tty0 ignore_loglevel" without having graphical access to the machine?

Comment: Yes, you can start the VM headless and edit your grub configuration. Here's some documentation for Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters 
You can search for other distributions online, if you're not using Ubuntu.

Comment: Note: It would be wise to take a snapshot of your VM prior to making changes to your bootloader (grub.)

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer or delete this altogether. [answer]

Comment: Thanks, @Rob. I was not aware and edited the answer.

Comment: How can I actually connect to a VM running headlessly? Is an RDP client the only option? I can ssh into the physical machine on which the VM is running, but is there a chance to log into the VM? Need not be graphically, command line would be enough.

Comment: I would suggest reading the VirtualBox documentation. If the machine is running headless, you can obtain the guest's IP address using VBoxManage and SSH to it. The command usage is: `VBoxManage guestproperty get <vmname> <pattern>` Example: `VBoxManage guestproperty get vm_name "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"`

Comment: Thanks, that returns "No value set!"

Comment: Then, you may want to start it "Normal" and check whether or not you're getting an IP address in the virtual console. Your network configuration may not be set correctly for the guest.